# Do I need to change my font stack when a web page is viewed on a high DPI Tablet or computer?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, font-size

I am using this font definition for my CSS:

```
html {
    font-size: 95%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
```

I would like my application to also show good text on a PC, iOS and Android tablet. However I understand that some of these show higher resolutions than others.  Already all my applications make use of rem for sizing of text, padding, button heights.

Do I need to do anything different for high DPI devices or would this font-stack be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to replace fonts or do anything different for higher density screens.

Just do some testing and check whether your fonts look good on different resolutions and if not then you can fix them using css3 media queries for appropriate resolution.

*It could have been more of a comment but I cant comment because of low reputation*

Comment: Hello Haider. I upvoted you so hope you're reputation is a bit more now. Do you personally have experience of using a similar font stack? I am wondering if my choice of Arial, Helvetica is reasonable.

Comment: Thank you @SamanthaJ. I have used this stack more than once but my first priority is Helvetica in this stack.